# Moving very large (~100 Gb) from one server to the other

Tags: file-transfer, large-data

We're moving servers, and I need to transfer all the data from Server A to Server B.

I have a tar.gz of about 100Gb that contains all the Server A files.

I'd really like to avoid downloading the file locally on my computer, and uploading it to Server B.

I only have ftp access to Server A.  That means no ssh.  However, I do have ssh access to Server B.

What's the best way to transfer the file ?  I was thinking of moving my tar.gz file to public_html temporarily, and download it using wget.  Would that work ?
Otherwise, I could use ftp through an ssh session on Server B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
ssh user@serverB
nohup wget -bqc ftp://path/largefile.tar.gz
```

wget options:

```
-b : run in background
-q : quiet
-c : resume broken download (means you can restart if it breaks)
```

This runs wget in the background so (hopefully) if you exit the ssh shell it'll keep going.  Ok, I think you need nohup to ensure that is the case when/if you logout

Because you're initiating the download from serverB, your desktop machine isn't involved in the file transfer except to set it up.

Comment: Or use `wget` in a `screen` / `tmux` session.

Comment: That worked out great.  Even lost the ssh connection during transfer and it completed.  Thanks.

Comment: @ManuelLafond - Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

If it's not very sensitive data and your connection is safe enough, ssh into B and download straight from A via ftp. SSH will make your download considerably slower because of the encryption work overhead. If possible split the 100GB file in multiple ones, especially if the ftp server on A doesn't support download resume.